# Migrate Drupal fields to WordPress as custom fields

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drupal, database-migration

While migrating Drupal to WordPress (following the guides on [official page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Drupal)), I haven't found any way to migrate Drupal "Fields" to WordPress as "Custom Fields". Since I'm very new to Drupal, please suggest how can I do this. Any code samples, links or ideas to solve this issue will be appreciated.

Additional info:

1. Drupal  v6.28; Wordpress v3.6;
2. Please consider that I'm new to Drupal not the WordPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I developed a solution how to migrate Drupal Fields to WordPress as Custom Fields (post meta) :

First, lets say that we've a custom Content Type under Drupal. Let say it has a "key" `my_custom_type`, then, if this Content Type has got Fields the database will have a table named

```
`content_type_my_custom_type`
```

This table will contains Fields related to this Content Type. For example:

```
    nid | vid | field_xxx_xxx | field_yyy_yyy | ...
    _______________________________________________
    10  |  1  | the_value_x01 | the_value_y01 | ...
    11  |  2  | the_value_x11 | the_value_y11 | ...
    11  |  3  | the_value_x12 | the_value_y12 | ...
    11  |  4  | the_value_x13 | the_value_y13 | ...
```

where

1. `nid` - node id (node UNIQUE id)
2. `vid` - version id (current node revision's UNIQUE id; there may be unlimited number of revisions per node)
3. `field_xxx_xxx` - Field KEY

The task is to move the Fields to **existing** WordPress post as this post Custom Field (post_meta).

Considering the structure of `$TABLEPREFIX_post_meta` table in Wordpress (thx to your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18367517/2080781), Chris) :

1. `meta_id` - index
2. `post_id` - ID of associated post
3. `meta_key` - name of the field
4. `meta_value` - value of the field

, we can use this query:

```
INSERT INTO wordpress.wp_postmeta
    (post_id, meta_value, meta_key)        
    SELECT 
        tt.nid `post_id`,
        tt.field_xxx_xxx `meta_value`,
        'field_xxx_xxx' `meta_key`  
        FROM drupal.content_type_my_custom_type tt
        INNER JOIN
            (
            SELECT nid, MAX(vid) AS MaxVID
            FROM temp.content_type_my_custom_type
            GROUP BY nid
            ) groupedtt ON tt.nid = groupedtt .nid AND tt.vid = groupedtt.MaxVID
```

Clarification: we've making an insertion of 3 fields, where

1. `post_id` equals to `nid`
2. `meta_value` equals to  `field_xxx_xxx` (replace for your)
3. `meta_key` equals to string `"field_xxx_xxx"`

We also making an inner join to select max `vid` value (latest revision).

This method is not fully automated but works like a charm.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

They're stored in the WordPress database in the `wp_postmeta` table, with the following fields:

- `meta_id` - index
- `post_id` - ID of associated post
- `meta_key` - name of the field
- `meta_value` - value of the field

I don't know much about how Drupal stores its field data, but as long as there are post IDs, keys, and values, you can create a query to migrate it to WordPress.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but, honestly, it does not helps me due to the fact that I'm new to Drupal and its database structure in difference to Wordpress. So, technically, the question is how to deal with Drupal Structure.

Comment: I peeked at a Drupal 6 database that I have laying around, and it has tables named something like `content_field_XXXX`.  Otherwise I couldn't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Thank you for the info, and you're right this name pattern describes the Drupal Fields table. But it contains only Field instances and i'd like to have more details about how it tied with the content. Sorry for taking your time, I'd love to accept your answer unless i get the detailed one.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the [WP Ultimate CSV Importer Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/). This powerful tool allows the import of posts from a csv file, it also automatically creates categories and custom fields assigned to posts. Exporting tables from the database to a CSV file can be done in phpMyAdmin.

I don’t know the structure of Drupal database, so i don’t know how much this helps, but this tool has helped me in similar situations.